# Sharing progress bar between activities

Tags: android, progress-bar

1. A progress bar declared in the headerlayout
2. Access the progress bar from Activity 1 and change the state
3. Access the same progress bar from Activity 2 will not containing the same state but these two activities having the same header layout

Answer (score 0):

You can use a merge layout or an include layout to share the xml layout part between your activities.

As for the status of the progress bar, I suggest you use a SharedPreferences to store your progress when you change activity.

Comment: I actually have this problem too, right now i have a custom header that has a progressbar view spinner style, for example i want to set the visibility on and launch a thread  do something, and if i change activities i want to maintain the state on if the thread is still doing something....

Comment: you should try to keep track of your thread rather than trying to keep the actual view

Comment: Can you elaborate more?, my progressbar view is set to hide in the xml , but i suspect this not the best way to do it

Comment: Seems i managed to make it work except that pressing back button will show the screen in the sate it was after changing to new activity. tried to change visibility in the onResume method but it didnt work...

Comment: may be there is some action you need to add in the onBackPressed of your second activity to make sure the progress can be seen on the first one. Or may be you can prevent the user from coming back to the first activity?